# "Undefined symbols" issue when compiling basic C++ program on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

Test program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

`g++ test.cpp`

Output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in test-a6ddbc.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-a6ddbc.o
(...etc)
```

When I Google the error above, it usually [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251766/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-std-1localeuse-facetstd-1) to use `g++` instead of `gcc`, but I'm already doing that.

How do I successfully compile the program?

Operating system: Mac OS Big Sur 11.4

`which g++` outputs `/usr/bin/g++`

`g++ --version` outputs:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: What do the commands `which g++`  and `g++ --version` show? Are you running on an Intel Mac or on an M1 one?

Comment: And is it an Intel or an M1 mac?

Comment: It's an Intel Mac.

Comment: if you try the same with `clang++` - what happens?

Comment: @BitTickler Exactly the same thing happens.

Comment: Hmm ok, that's strange. Did you try to run `xcode-select --install` and `sudo xcodebuild -license` (with `agree` at the end) again?

Comment: @t.niese I ran `xcode-select --install` earlier today, but I'll try both again now.

Comment: `xcode-select` says it's already installed, and agreeing to the terms of `xcodebuild -license` doesn't change the output. (Earlier today I ran `rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and reinstalled the commandline tools, but didn't help, unfortunately)

Comment: What does `g++ -v test.cpp` show?

Comment: run `g++ -v test.cpp`. It will show you what `g++` really uses.

Comment: @t.niese  I've uploaded the output here: https://sf.gl/f/a6c27af.txt

Comment: try `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`?

Comment: And what does `g++ -Xlinker -v test.cpp ` show?

Comment: @t.niese Here's the output of that: https://sf.gl/f/6d5e412.txt

Comment: On a first look there seems nothing wrong with the output. Did you somehow try to install g++ or clang in a different why before?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I've just installed `llvm` via Homebrew, and with that, I'm able to compile it successfully using `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ test.cpp`. But I'm also thinking something is very wrong with my mac OS / Xcode installation.